# Get row has Max value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I want to get `staff_id` = `AZ` has MAX(`step`) value of this table (name: test).

| id | general_id | staff_id | step |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | A1 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | AZ | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | A2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | A3 | 1 |
| 5 | 5 | A4 | 2 |
| 6 | 5 | AZ | 3 |

```sql
SELECT MAX(step) AS STEP, staff_id
FROM test AS t 
WHERE staff_id = AZ 
GROUP BY general_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For just one staff, you can use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select *
from test
where staff_id = 'AZ'
order by step desc limit 1
```

If you want to do this for multiple staffs at once, then one option uses a correlated subquery:

```
select *
from test t
where t.step = (select max(t1.step) from test t1 where t1.staff_id = t.staff_id)
```

Another feature of this approach is that it allows top ties, if any.

Or, in MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        rank() over(partition by staff_id order by step desc) rn
    from test t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: if I want to get the `general_id` rows containing staff_id = `AZ` with the MAX` step` value, what should I do? 
the result I want contains `id` including 4,5,6